# Display view field on pages with specific path alias

Tags: 7, views, path-aliases

i have a `view` block - that shows 3 last images of my content type `sidebar image`(block is displayed on every page). Content type has two fields - `image` and `path` - url path alias, for example 'content/example'.

By default i need to show this 3 images that has been created without `path`(its not mandatory field) - i did this its works fine, but now when user create new node of `sidebar image` with path alias `'content/example'` - i need to show this picture in my view  instead of one of the three default on this path.

The path can be - either view or node or taxonomy term.

I tried to create contextual filter with `path` field and provide default value, but kinda stuck here because its a path alias.

Any suggestions?

What i think of is to parse URL get the path, and then query to DB - and check is my path is equal to image path so i can change the query of view.

Comment: What is the reason for the path field? What does it accomplish?

Comment: path its just a url without domain name - for example full url `http://exaple.com/content/test` and the path is `content/test`path is needed in order to display the desired image on the right page inside this view, I probably need to parse url in parts and make changes in preprocess_views

Comment: Not sure if it would work, but you might look at a contextual filter, if I understand your intent. If the filter does work, though, it will only display those images which are a match. If there is no match, you can configure a default behaviour. Views is great for standard use cases and prototyping, but you might have to look at a custom block.